# Subtract two columns from different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to subtract column `Country` from DataFrame `dfA` with column `Country` in DataFrame `dfB`.

I'm trying the following code:

```
A_minus_B = dfA['Country'] - dfB['Country']

Typerror: - with str & str
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
dfA Country
1. United States
2. Puerto Rico
3. Colombia

dfB Country
1. Puerto Rico
2. Argentina
3. Canada

A_minusB Country
1. United States
2. Colombia
3. Argentina
```

Comment: Help us to help you. Offer a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The logic is quite unclear. Why is Argentina (but not Canada) appearing in A-B?

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([dfA, dfB]).drop_duplicates(keep=False, ignore_index=True)

         Country
0  United States
1       Colombia
2      Argentina
3         Canada
```

Comment: ```.reset_index(drop=True)``` ;-)

Comment: @LaurentB. Prefer use `ignore_index=True` instead of `.reset_index(...)` to avoid to return another copy of the dataframe. Just bad copy/paste for my output.

Comment: Right, this is less time consumer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below

```
A_minus_B = dfA.loc[~dfA['Country'].isin(dfB['Country']), 'Country']
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create `dfC = dfA.merge(dfB, "Country")`.

With everything in a single dataframe, then you will then be
in a good position to perform the subtraction.

---

You neglected to put a reproducible example in your question.
Once you work out the technical details,
[describe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
the solution and the results that you obtain.